# Will process ids be recycled? What if you reach the maximal id?

Tags: kernel, process

Process IDs are strictly increasing, but if your system runs long enough and there is a lot of processes terminating and starting, you could at some point reach the limit of the underlying integral type (on my system it seems to be a signed int) where no larger pid would exists. Would this cause old unused ids (of processes that finished) to be recycled (i.e. handed out a second time)? What if somebody is waiting for that pid to terminate but didn't check in a *looong* time?

Comment: This seems like a near duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22425/why-new-pid-is-smaller-than-the-old-ones/22427#comment30365_22427

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Process IDs are not strictly increasing on any UNIX-like operating system I know of. Your question is based on a false assumption.

The only [requirements on process IDs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html) are:

> A process ID shall not be reused by the system until the process lifetime ends. In addition, if there exists a process group whose process group ID is equal to that process ID, the process ID shall not be reused by the system until the process group lifetime ends. A process that is not a system process shall not have a process ID of 1.

Comment: So that means, they **are** reused. But what if I wait for a child process to finish? By coincidence its process id could be reused before I get a chance to check it, right?

Comment: No, that's impossible. The process is not finished until it reports its exit value to its parent. That is one of its jobs, and until it has done that, it is not finished.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - not sure how readable this will be in a comment but - linux is pretty sequential. 
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ a.out
24506
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ a.out
24507
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ a.out
24508
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ a.out
24509
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ cat pid.cc
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("%d\n", getpid());
   return 0;
}

Comment: Most OSes are sequential until they wrap around. Some reserve certain ranges for processes of different types. A few have been random.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That was my point - you said "are not strictly increasing on any UNIX-like operating system I know of" - you remember that super security flaw in Debian because they were using the PID as the salt for hashing ;-) - with only 65K of PID's not the best salt

Comment: Yes, they are not strictly increasing on an UNIX-like operating system I know of. If you know of one where they are strictly increasing, you haven't mentioned it yet. (*Strictly* increasing means that they *never* decrease.) I could imagine an OS with 64-bit PIDs that did that, but I don't know of any.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Agree - I was reading your answer as they 'mostly do not' but actually that is not what you wrote. Funny - just checked my OS and pid_t is 4 bytes - but nothing > 65K - seems a little small in todays world - will search the POSIX specs